# MVC define @section for all views in area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a container in my layout where I'd like to display a list of menu items, and I'd like for additional menu items to be displayed based on which area of the site we are viewing.

I know that I could do this with a `@section`, but that means I would have to copypaste the section contents in every single view within the area, which would be a maintenance mess and a nasty violation of DRY.  Multiple per-area layouts would also be undesirable code duplication.

It would be good to do it in the _ViewStart partial, but apparently MVC doesn't allow `@section`s to be defined in partials.  What else can I do?

Comment: Create a layout view that the area uses and put the menu list inside of that layout?  That would mean a layout per area, but a heck of a lot more concise.  Alternatively, could you make an Html Helper that would return a partial view (your menu) based on the current area that you are in?  A little uglier since you would have to pull the area name from the RouteValue dictionary, but even less repitition

Comment: Everything else in the layout except for my menu container should be shared across the whole site, though. Duplicating all that other content would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Controller and Action to cater for this, I generally use something like `NavigationController` with a `MainMenu` action or similar.

In your action:

```
public ActionResult MainMenu()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

The from any where on your site layouts or views you can use:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("MainMenu", "Navigation"); }
```

This also means that you can include any business logic in your action and pass a model to your MainMenu, maybe for checking roles etc.

Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making an action method in some generic controller that returns the correct partial view with the proper menu items.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult GetSubMenu(){
   var areaName = ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
   switch(areaName){
      case "Admin":
         return PartialView("_adminSubMenu");
      ....
      case default:
         //not sure on how to return nothing exactly
         return null;
   }
}
```

In your layout

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetSubMenu","GenericControllerName");}
```